# "This leads to the question" followed by a comma or a colon

Tags: word-choice, punctuation, colons, question-mark

I am saying something along the lines of "this leads to the question, why does x happen" or "this brings up an interesting question, why does x happen" but I'm not sure if it should be a comma or a colon.

For example:

> This brings up an interesting question: why does x happen
> *vs.*
> This brings up an interesting question, why does x happen

What's the best way of saying this? Also, do I end the sentence with a question mark?

Comment: The colon is more appropriate punctuation here, as the question is really the explanation of the first part of the sentence. It is a direct question, so a final question mark is also required. :-)